# Getting a "Caused by error in `UseMethod()" when using Count function after Group_by

Tags: r, group-by, error-handling, count

I am trying to create an equal weight column within my dataframe, by dividing 100 by the number of records per unique date (marketdate).

I used Group_by(marketdate) and then used a Count function, but I keep getting the error below.

Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "Date"

Below is the code I am using.
Should I be using a different function to count the number of records per date?
Would really appreciate any help with this issue.

```
#Add ff_equal column
df <- df |>
  group_by(marketdate) |>
  mutate(ff_equal = 100 / count(marketdate)) |>
  ungroup()
```

Comment: `count(marketdate)` isn't correct. Please look at the examples given in the help file of `?count` which may help. In this case maybe you are looking for `n()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count doesn't work with date type columns, you can use n() which counts the rows in each group. try below code should work

```
df <- df |>
  group_by(marketdate) |>
  mutate(ff_equal = 100 / n()) |>
  ungroup()
```

Comment: You are more than welcome Richard, glad I could help.